# Cannot import io.quarkus.elasticsearch.restclient.lowlevel.ElasticsearchClientConfig

Tags: java, elasticsearch, quarkus

I cannot import io.quarkus.elasticsearch.restclient.lowlevel.ElasticsearchClientConfig in my Java code.

Cannot find it anywhere in local jar or online repo.

Code from: [Quarkus - Connecting to an Elasticsearch cluster](https://quarkus.io/guides/elasticsearch#programmatically-configuring-elasticsearch)

Which jar dependency does the annotation @ElasticsearchClientConfig locate in?

Comment: You can try following the project setup part of this guide to depend on elasticsearch: https://quarkus.io/guides/elasticsearch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is available from the `quarkus-elasticsearch-rest-client` extension or the `quarkus-elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client` extension starting with Quarkus 1.12.

Comment: Yes, that's because the version of quarkus i used was too low to have this annotaion.